# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars during SVM training

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I have a weird error with SVM

my labels are as follows:

```
labels: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

embeddings are like:

```
data["embeddings"]:
[array([ 0.05140932,  0.05402263, ... ,  0.02575628], dtype=float32), array([ 0.05858443, -0.05192663, ... , 0.01924052, 0.1784615 ,  -0.12531035, -0.04654732], dtype=float32)]
```

the length of both labels and embeddings are the same. The above embeddings are only [0:2] part of the whole

```
recognizer = SVC(C=1.0, kernel="linear", probability=True)
recognizer.fit(data["embeddings"],labels)
```

recognizer.fit() produces following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_embeddings.py", line 52, in <module>
    recognizer.fit(data["features"],labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py", line 146, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 747, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 531, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "/muho/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have also tried it by changing labels to this:

```
labels: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but it also didn't help. I don't know what or why should anything here be scalar.

Comment: `data['embeddings']` needs to be a numpy array (numeric dtype), or something it can turn into such,

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `data["embeddings"]` seems to be the issue. Its elements are 1-length Arrays because you can't access the values as a list but a tuple (values, dtype)
Use :

```
data_2 = [x[0] for x in data["embeddings"]]
recognizer.fit(data_2, labels)
```